# Postgresql max TransactionId > 4 billion

Tags: postgresql

The max transactionId of Postgresql should be 2^31 which is 2 billion, however, when I query the current transactionId from DB via select cast(txid_current() as text) I got the number 8 billion. why does this happen? The autovacuum_freeze_max_age is 200 million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html) for the function family you are using says:

> The internal transaction ID type (xid) is 32 bits wide and wraps around every 4 billion transactions. However, these functions export a 64-bit format that is extended with an "epoch" counter so it will not wrap around during the life of an installation.

Comment: Thanks. but why it will not wrap around just because it's 64-bit format? if it's the case why don't we use 64-bit  for the normal transaction id to prevent wrap around?

Comment: 64 bits is large enough that it is hard to conceive of wrap around happening within a time period anyone cares about (if you burn a million a second, which is way more than feasible, they would last half a million years).  We don't store them that way due to size and due to backwards compatibility.